# $f$ is increasing and bounded, $f$ is differentiable. Show that $\int_a^b f'(x)dx=f(b)-f(a)$.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, monotone-functions

> $f$ is increasing and bounded, $f$ is differentiable. Show that $\int_a^b f'(x)dx=f(b)-f(a)$.

Here the $\int_a^b$ is in the Lebesgue sense. How to prove it? By Lebesgue theorem, we only have $\int_a^b f'(x)dx \leq f(b)-f(a)$. How to use the assumption $f$ is differentiable? We have no assumption on the Riemann integrability of $f'$, but only have the Lebesgue integrability of $f'$!

Comment: The statement is wrong : for example [Cantor function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_function).

Comment: @Surb The Cantor function is not differentiable everywhere...

Comment: You should precise it in your post, because working with Lebesgue integrale normally implies that you work with class of function rather than functions...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\int_a^{b} f'(x)dx \leq f(b)-f(a) <\infty$ and $f'\geq 0$. Hence, $f$ is differentiable (at every point) with its derivative in $L^{1}$. This implies that $f$ is absoluetly continuous and $\int_a^{b} f'(x)dx = f(b)-f(a)$. This non-trivial result is proved in Rudin's RCA.